# Convergence to Charactersitic Function a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm working on the following problem in Folland:

> If $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\chi_{E_n} \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$, then $f$ is equal (a.e.) to the characteristic function of a measurable set.

There are two hints given [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~toro/Courses/06-07/524/9-hw.pdf):

> 1. (Ex 3) If $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $X$, then $\{ x: \lim f_n(x) \text{ exists}\}$ is a measurable set.
> 2. (Ex 5) If $X= A \cup B$ where $A,B \in \mathcal{M}$, a function $f$ on $X$ is measurable iff $f$ measurable on $A$ and $B$.

I understand the idea, I think --

$\chi_{E_n} \rightarrow f$  in $L^1$ will imply a subsequence converging to $f$ a.e. The limit will be $1$'s and $0$'s so will be a characteristic function. I'm having trouble putting it together rigorously though. In particular I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472569/problem-2-36-in-folland-is-my-solution-correct) whose accepted answer mentions convergence for $k$ large enough, which I don't understand becuase we converge a.e (what if we blow up?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hints seem a bit silly to me.  If you know the fact that (*) an $L^1$-convergent sequence has an a.e.-convergent subsequence, then what you have just said is exactly the proof: since $\chi_{E_n}(\omega)$ is $0$ or $1$ for any $n$, then $f(\omega)$ must also be zero or one a.e.  Moreover $f$ is a measurable function by assumption.  So if we let $E = \{f = 1\}$ (which is measurable) then $f = \chi_E$ a.e.

If you don't know, or aren't allowed to use, the fact (*), then I guess you have to proceed differently, and maybe the hints are useful in that case.  I haven't thought much about it yet.

Comment: Okay: I guess I'm specifically having trouble with being explicit about "since $\chi_{E_n}(\omega)$ is $0$ or $1$ for any $n$, then $f(\omega)$ must also be zero or one a.e." Also $f$ measurable by ass'n? I know that for a function to be measurable, its preimage must be measurable. I don't get a measurable preimage, unless I limit on a measurable set. How do I know I limit on a measurable set?

Comment: @yoshi: This is an exercise from baby analysis: if a sequence $a_n$ of real numbers consists of zeros and ones, then the limit, if it exists, is necessarily either 0 or 1.  You should be able to prove it directly from the definition of sequence convergence, or elementary facts about it.  We are just applying this with $a_n =\chi_{E_n}(\omega)$, for each $\omega$.

Comment: @yoshi: Next, look up the definition of $L^1$ convergence.  In order for it to even make sense, the limiting function has to be measurable, so the assumption that $f$ is measurable is implied by the statement of the problem.

Comment: @yoshi: Indeed, the "baby analysis exercise" is equivalent to the statement that the two-point set $\{0,1\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.